# dotCover Upload to Sonar from Jenkins Plugin

Tags: jenkins, sonarqube, dotcover, sonarqube-msbuild-runner

So I am having trouble uploading our dotCover results from Jenkins to our Sonar instance. We are using the SonarScanner for MSBuild plugin. All of the documentation I have found like here: https://docs.sonarqube.org/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=6389770#CodeCoverageResultsImport(C#,VB.NET)-dotCover

Shows how to do it from the command line. We are using the plugin. There is an area for additional arguments that I have added what I assume is an added argument like on the command line. Here is how I have it set up:
[image]

So that is the argument that everything shows to add to the end of the command line portion, but for some reason it doesn't add coverage to Sonar. Does anyone see anything obvious I am missing here? I have been stuck on this for a while. Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

So as it turns out I had:

```
/d:sonar.cs.dotcover.reportsPath=
```

It should have been with an s at the end:

```
 /d:sonar.cs.dotcover.reportsPaths=
```